# How can I replace "bash: $COMMAND: command not found" message?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

Any help would be appreciated.

Basically, I want to replace:

```
~]$ obvfake
bash: obvfake: command not found
```

With:

```
~]$ obvfake
[*] command not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care?

Comment: [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). You have the freedom to improve it. So get its source code, study it, improve it.... But are you sure it is worth your time?

Answer (score 9):

`bash` version 4 introduces a hook for handling missing commands; add the following to your `.bashrc` file.

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    printf "[*] command not found\n"
    return 127
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering is there a way to handle this error, print our custom message, and then let the system print the default message after?

Comment: got one: `command_not_found_handle () { fortune insults; return 127 }` if, of course, you have the relevant fortunes file (from `perl_fortune`). A bit like sudo insulting you on wrong password

Answer (score 3):

You can write this to your `.bashrc`:

```
function error_handler {
  if [ $? -eq 127 ]; then
      echo "[*] command not found"
  fi  
}

trap 'error_handler' ERR
```

This will still show the `bash: obvfake: command not found` though. You can suppress this by doing:

```
obvfake 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Not sure where i'm failing or if the intended outcome is not what I expect but I have tried that. It just prints both.

>obvfake
>bash: obvfake: command not found
>[*] command not found

Comment: @CarlosSanchez, added some explanation for that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply redirect errors to `/dev/null`. If `obvfake` returns an exit code greater than 0 then it will echo your custom error message.

```
obvfake 2>/dev/null || echo "[*] command not found"
```

This might be a little be too general since it will not distinguish between error codes. So we could  check for a specific exit code.

```
obvfake 2>/dev/null || {
    if (( $? == 127 )); then
        echo "[*] command not found"
    fi
}
```

If I'd want to check a lot of error codes I'd replace the `if` expression with a `case` statement.
For the ease of use you could integrate that functionality inside your script and maybe wrap it up into a function to reuse it at various points of failure.

You pretty much want to know more about [redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) in `bash`. :)

EDIT: I guess I misinterpreted the original question. I thought `obvfake` is a custom script complaining about commands being called but not found on the system.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by chepner... you can customize the default message by replacing the bash function (handles Signal 127 or command-not-found functionality) with the one designed by you and include that function in .bashrc script.

```
# function that handles command-not-found message.
command_not_found_handle() {

 echo -e "My Friend, '$1' is a typo. Please correct it and re-enter the command."  
  return 127

}
```

You also can check this at: http://bitdiffferent.com/command-not-found/

Comment: But your example doesn't produce the output the OP is asking for. And if it did, it'd be a copy/paste from the answer posted by @chepner

Comment: @Peter Well, I want to add my comment on the post of chepner.. but I was unable to make a comment due to some restrictions thereby made a new post. I tried it was working and published the same as article on my website. Is this wrong?

Comment: _"Is this wrong?"_ -- in my opinion, yes. Stack Overflow isn't the right place to advertise your web site, and so far as I can see the _only_ contribution/added value your answer adds is the advertising of your web site. Completely off-topic and not useful here. (This is regardless of the question of whether you can post comments or not, but on that question, just because SO doesn't let you post comments, that's not a reason to post your comment as if it were an answer).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will take care of it.